# How to write a large file to disk on each worker

Tags: apache-spark

Newbie to spark.  I have a large data file that needs to be writen to disk on each worker before my application runs.  RDD.mapPartitions seems like what I should be using, but I'm not sure if each worker contains only a single partition and how to create an RDD guaranteed to have a partition for each worker.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

RDD.saveAsTextFile will write to disk from each worker, all you need to do is make sure that you have the right number of partitions (you probebly want to set the number of partitions to the number of cores you have available for workers in the cluster) for example:

```
val files = sc.textFile("file:...")
val prt = files.repartition(5)
prt.saveAsTextFile("file:...")
```

Also you should note that RDD.mapPartition executes the map operation for all the element in the partition, map is a transformation which means it is expected transform the data and is lazy.